# Sorting a Linked List in ascending order and printing sorted List

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++14, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a linked list in ascending order and stuck at this point here. THe rest of the code is working fine (appending, prepending functions). I was trying to use the bubble sort algorithm here.

However, the output shows segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong over here?

```
void sortLinkedList(Node** head_ref)
{
    Node* slow_node =(*head_ref);
    Node* fast_node=NULL;
    Node* temp=NULL;
    while(slow_node->next!=NULL)
    {
        fast_node=slow_node->next;
        while(fast_node->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(fast_node->data>fast_node->next->data)
            {
                temp->data=fast_node->data;
                fast_node->data=fast_node->next->data;
                fast_node->next->data=temp->data;
            }   
            fast_node=fast_node->next;
        }
        slow_node=slow_node->next;
    }
}

void printList(Node** head_ref)
{
    Node* new_node=(*head_ref);

    while(new_node!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<new_node->data<<"-->";
        new_node=new_node->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL";
    cout<<endl;
}



int main()
{
    Node* head=new Node();

    head=NULL;

    insertAtEnd(&head,2);
     printList(&head);
    insertAtEnd(&head,3);
     printList(&head);  
    insertAtEnd(&head,2);
     printList(&head);  
    insertAtEnd(&head,4);
     printList(&head);  
     insertAtEnd(&head,5);
     printList(&head);  

    cout<<"Sorted List"<<endl;
    sortLinkedList(&head);
    printList(&head);

}
```

Output

```
2-->NULL
2-->3-->NULL
2-->3-->2-->NULL
2-->3-->2-->4-->NULL
2-->3-->2-->4-->5-->NULL
Sorted List
Segmentation fault (Core dumped)
```

Comment: did you try runing it with debugger?

Comment: where is the Node def?

Comment: ... Where do you assign to temp?

Comment: There is no point in passing `Node**` to the printing function. Use `const Node*`.

Comment: Usually a linked list sort will re-point nodes, rather than swap data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
Node* temp=NULL;
```

and then you

```
temp->data=fast_node->data;
```

and it goes BOOM because `temp` is a null pointer.

If you're going to swap the nodes' data, you don't need a whole node, just one of whatever type `data` is:

```
 if(fast_node->data>fast_node->next->data)
 {
     whatever_data_is temp = fast_node->data;
     fast_node->data = fast_node->next->data;
     fast_node->next->data = temp;
 }
```

but there already is a swapping function in your standard library, so you can simplify:

```
 if (fast_node->data>fast_node->next->data)
 {
     std::swap(fast_node->data, fast_node->next->data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the bubble sort, is the swap operation. You use the temp, which is NULL, and try to access the data element. This triggers the segmentation fault.

In the simplest case you can use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). Your bubble sort would looks like

```
void sortLinkedList(Node** head_ref)
{
    Node* slow_node =(*head_ref);
    Node* fast_node=NULL;
    while(slow_node->next!=NULL)
    {
        fast_node=slow_node->next;
        while(fast_node->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(fast_node->data>fast_node->next->data)
            {
                std::swap(fast_node->data, fast_node->next->data);
            }   
            fast_node=fast_node->next;
        }
        slow_node=slow_node->next;
    }
}
```